# image link to another image(image gallery)

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

So I basically want to be able to click on any of the small images and have them display in the larger image area above them. Like a gallery. Its there anyway to do this with HTML/CSS?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="mainInfo">
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="displayImage">
        <a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery3.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbImage">
                    <a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery1.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery2.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery3.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery4.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery5.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery6.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.mainInfo {
height: 800px;
background-color:#FCFCFC;
color:#001D5D;
}

 .gallery {
float: left;
}

.thumbImage {
margin-top:575px;
}
 .thumbImage img {
width:140px;
height:auto;
margin-left:15px;
 }
.displayImage {
margin:89px 0 0 177px;
}

.displayImage img {
width:600px;
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. But, you need a little bit of JavaScript here.

Here I am giving you a similar code which you have written above.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script>
function display(imgElement){
    document.getElementById('displayimg').setAttribute('src',imgElement.getAttribute('src'));
    }

</script>
<style>
#display{
border:solid 1px blue;
width:90%;
height:60%;
margin:auto;
}
#select{
padding:10% 1% 1% 1%;
width:95%;
height:25%;
mrgin:auto;
}
#display img{
border:solid 1px red;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#select img{
border:solid cyan 1px;
floatLleft;
width:50px;
height:25px;
}
#select a{
border:solid green 1px;
}
#select a:hover,a:active{
border:solid yellow 1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display">
    <img id="displayimg">
</div>
<div id="select">
<img id="selectimg" src="D:\D drive\147266.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
<img id="selectimg" src="D:\D drive\d1x5u3.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
<img id="selectimg" src="D:\D drive\ct0.jpg" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
    <img id="selectimg" src="D:\D drive\aftn.jpg" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
</div>
 </body>
```

and the output will be like this

[image]

This is just as simple as your requirement. but you need to  do a lot more to design Image Gallery.

If you wanted to display the image when you place your mouse on the image, just replace **onclick** with **onmouseover**.

Comment: I am just having a play around with it now. I have the javascript in an external file and have linked it to the html but the script doesn't seem to be working. Is there anything else I need to add to the script when its linked externally? Sorry don't know much about javascript

Comment: You have to change the script tag as `<script src="image.js"></script>` and remove the JavaScript code between the <script> tags and place in another file named **image.js**.
Then, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks I did figure it out

Answer (score 1):

No, when ever you want something triggered by a click, then you have to use javascript.  The closest you could get is by using a mouse hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using **CSS** only.

Take a look at these websites http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ and http://fancybox.net/

You can download and use those plugins according to your needs or write your own plugin if you have enough skills in **Javascript** or use any other **library** (such as **jQuery** - http://jquery.com/) written on **Javascript**.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with your current HTML and CSS alone. What you can do with that code is add a little javascript to achieve what you want.

So, since you didn't mention javascript as an option, I've assumed that you don't know how to do it using javascript and I took the liberty to write you an fiddle so you can figure out what's your next step if you want to do this with javascript.

It might seem hard to understand now, but as soon as you start learn actual javascript, you won't feel the need to search for plugins, widgets or even help to do anything you want on your webpage, apps, etc.

Feel free to ask for explanation on any part of the code.

#### Fiddle

(i didn't change the images, so they don't appear. If you want to see some image, just change their src)

Javascript:

```
var thumbImages = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbImage')[0].children;

[].forEach.call(thumbImages, function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName('displayImage')[0];
        gallery.innerHTML = '';
        gallery.appendChild(e.currentTarget.cloneNode(true));
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: Yes Matheus, this is a good solution. But, I think we need to remove the child before adding the child element to the "displayImage". Othrewise, `appendChild()` will add another child along with the one which you already having as a child in th "displayImage" div.

I hope we have to use `removeChild()`.

But Please correct, if I am wrong.Because, just I am also a learner, not an expert.

Comment: I think it is already removed on gallery.innerHTML = ' ', but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ohh....sorry dear...., I didn't observed it correctly. Yes, you are right. No such problem will be there.
Thank you.